# Without calculating, tell which is a perfect square: 1022121; 2042122; 3063126; 4083128

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I am trying aptitude questions but was struck on this problem.

> Which of the following numbers is a perfect square?
>
> A) $1022121\quad$ B) $2042122\quad$ C) $3063126\quad$ D)$4083128$

([original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hn71.jpg))

As a perfect square always has last digit $0$, $1$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $9$. So, B and D are eliminated.

But I don't know how to eliminate A or C.

The answer is A.

Comment: $1022121=(1000+b)^2=1000^2+b^2+2000b$ and if you play with numbers you realize that b is 11( see you have 121 in right )

Comment: Well I can think of three quite easy ways to eliminate C - what have you tried? What might you know which could help you? Best to think for yourself as you probably do know enough for this, rather than asking for help too early. That way your mathematical imagination will develop faster ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect squares give remainder $0$ or $1$ after division by $3$ and also $4$, both of which can be checked quickly. The C gives same remainder as $26$ after division by $4$, which is $2\neq 0,1$.

Comment: This was one of my three - divisible by $2$ but not by $4$

Answer (score 3):

Using the method of casting out nines, you can see that $3\mid3\,063\,126$, but $9\nmid3\,063\,126$. So, $3\,063\,126$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: This was one of my three - divisible by $3$ but not by $9$

Answer (score 1):

For the final two digits of a square in base $10$ you have  $00$ or $25$ or $E1$ or $E4$ or $[O]6$ or $E9$ where O and E stand for odd and even. You cannot have $E6$.

Just to complete the three methods I spotted, since two have been given by others. This is a modest extension of your existing method.